# Async request to get user details from other php file not working

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make an asynchronous request to process.php to get the details of the user with the given input username but am not getting any output.

If I try to directly do process.php?userName="1", it says array object q not defined where as if I submit the form, it queries on the index file itself.

Here is my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getUser(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "process.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <label for="userName">userName:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getUser(userName.value)">
</form>
<p id="data"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the process.php:

```
<?php

class User{
    public $userName;
    public $emailID;
    public $phoneNo;
    public $designation;
}

$user1 = new User();
$user1->userName = "1";
$user1->emailID = "1";
$user1->phoneNo = "1";
$user1->designation = "1";

$user2 = new User();
$user2->userName = "2";
$user2->emailID = "2";
$user2->phoneNo = "2";
$user2->designation = "2";

$user3 = new User();
$user3->userName = "3";
$user3->emailID = "3";
$user3->phoneNo = "3";
$user3->designation = "3";

$user4 = new User();
$user4->userName = "4";
$user4->emailID = "4";
$user4->phoneNo = "4";
$user4->designation = "4";

$user5 = new User();
$user5->userName = "4";
$user5->emailID = "4";
$user5->phoneNo = "4";
$user5->designation = "4";

$users = array($user1, $user2, $user3, $user4, $user5);

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$data = "";

if ($q !== "") {
  $q = strtolower($q);
  foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user->userName == $q){
        $data = "$user->emailID <br>" . "$user->phoneNo <br>" . "$user->designation ";
    }
  }
}

echo "$data";

?>
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to be working. The syntax also seems to be correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt to use the following line to test a GET, the parameter userName is not correct:

```
 process.php?userName="1"
```

Please change to

```
 process.php?q=1
```

So the following code should work:

PHP

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getUser(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "process.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <label for="userName">userName:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getUser(userName.value)">
</form>
<p id="data"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php

class User{
    public $userName;
    public $emailID;
    public $phoneNo;
    public $designation;
}

$user1 = new User();
$user1->userName = "1";
$user1->emailID = "1";
$user1->phoneNo = "1";
$user1->designation = "1";

$user2 = new User();
$user2->userName = "2";
$user2->emailID = "2";
$user2->phoneNo = "2";
$user2->designation = "2";

$user3 = new User();
$user3->userName = "3";
$user3->emailID = "3";
$user3->phoneNo = "3";
$user3->designation = "3";

$user4 = new User();
$user4->userName = "4";
$user4->emailID = "4";
$user4->phoneNo = "4";
$user4->designation = "4";

$user5 = new User();
$user5->userName = "4";
$user5->emailID = "4";
$user5->phoneNo = "4";
$user5->designation = "4";

$users = array($user1, $user2, $user3, $user4, $user5);

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$data = "";

if ($q !== "") {
  $q = strtolower($q);
  foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user->userName == $q){
        $data = "$user->emailID <br>" . "$user->phoneNo <br>" . "$user->designation ";
    }
  }
}

echo "$data";

?>
```

You may try the following sandbox to see the effect:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/sube/testprocess.php